# Elm VSCode plugin does not format on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, elm

I have copied the following question from the Elm Slack channel for posterity.

I am having trouble getting the [Elm VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Elmtooling.elm-ls-vscode) to format on save. I have set the absolute path to my global install of `elm-format` in `settings.json`. I have also set format on save for elm:

```
"[elm]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  },
```

I am on an Ubuntu machine, and format does not happen on save or with `Ctrl-Shift-I`. Does anyone see something that I might be missing?

Answer (score 9):

1. Install [elm-format](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format)
2. Install the extension [Elm Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Elmtooling.elm-ls-vscode) for VSCode, which includes syntax and error highlighting
3. Configure VS code `settings.json`:

```
"[elm]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The format on save timeout should not be an issue with VSCode 1.42 (Q1 2020)
See "[Better handling of slow save operations](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/113a3868f6ad836680ff7e82c2c890142178dac5/release-notes/v1_42.md#better-handling-of-slow-save-operations)":

> VS Code allows extensions to change a file's contents when saving files to disk.
>   Features like **`Format on Save`** and **`Fix on Save`** are examples.
>
> However, saving is a critical operation and extensions doing processing during a save must finish quickly so that the actual save operation can proceed.
>
> "Quickly" used to be enforced by VS Code with timeouts that would make VS Code cancel extension save participation.
>   That enforcement guaranteed speedy saving but could be frustrating because sometimes expected processing would not happen.
>
> **With this release, we have given up the timeout-based approach and instead show a progress notification that allows you to cancel extensions participating in save** ("`Save Participants`").
>   The notification lets you know that save operations are running and you can decide if you want to wait for a save participant to finish or not.

[image: https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_42/save-participant.png]

Answer (score 1):

The following are the responses and resolution.

Response from @stoft:

> Try installing elm-format locally or globally with npm, that helped me on MacOS.

Response from @razzee:

> please check two things:
>
> 1. are you on the latest elm-format version
> 2. increase the formatting timeout of vscode, unfortunately elm-format is  sometimes too slow "editor.formatOnSaveTimeout" is what the setting is called"

A global install of the latest version of `elm-format` was enough for format on save to work.

One case where format on save does not work by following these suggestions is in the [elm-0.19-workshop](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-0.19-workshop/). Format on save will not trigger on Elm files in `intro/part1/` or any of the other "part" directories.

Comment: `editor.formatOnSaveTimeout` no longer exists in vscode

Answer (score 1):

**Not setting the paths to elm-format** and elm-tests explicitely worked for me.

I ran
`npm install --global elm-test elm-format`
and let the extension figure out where it is.
As soon as I specify that `/home/a-teammate/npm/lib/node_modules/elm-test/bin/elm-format` is the elm-format I want to use, it stops working. Although pointing to the same elm-format.

Tested with elmtooling.elm-ls-vscode in version 0.9.4, elm 0.19.1 and elm-format 0.8.3

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Prettier formatter being installed as default. I resolved it by overriding formatter for Elm specifically:

```json
  "[elm]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "elmTooling.elm-ls-vscode"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have to open the root folder in VSCode containing `elm.json`.
Opening the `src` folder won't work.